# Is it possible to script SQL in a way that 'stages' the results?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If I have a table of people, and there's an 'age' column, and I want to query it I can do

`SELECT * FROM people WHERE age = 30`

If I want to limit it, I can put a `TOP` in.

`SELECT TOP 100 * FROM people WHERE age = 30`

But as an example of what I want, I am wondering, if I can get all people who are 30, and if there are less than 100, get people that are 25, and if there are still less than 100, get all the people who have the name 'jeff'.

Normally I would do (Pseudo-code warning):

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM people WHERE age = 30

if results < 100

SELECT TOP (100 - previousResultCount) * FROM people WHERE age = 25

if results < 100

SELECT TOP (100 - previousResultCounts) * FROM people WHERE name = 'jeff'
```

I am wondering how to perform this kind of query, and if it's possible to include an additional value in the results indicating that the result is from it having moved onto the next stage, eg. the above might be:

```
STEVE 30  1
STACY 30  1
SALLY 25  2
SUSAN 25  2
JEFF  19  3
```

The above is a simple example. What I'm actually doing is full-text search queries, eg. show me results where `name = query`, `name contains query`, `name contains all words in query but in a different order` etc. and I want to combine them all into a single query because I would assume this would be MUCH faster, especially if I add additional WHERE clauses such as age=30.

I always want 100 results back, and they always have to be ranked so that perfect matches appear first. If the data is jumbled up and I do the above as one by query WHERE a OR b OR c I would have to have the 3rd column above to ORDER BY and use with TOP.

My fear is that if I do OR OR OR, include a rank somehow and then order it by that rank and select the top it will do a ton of unnecessary calculations, for example it could potentially have to compute every single row in the database to get the ranks in order to put them in order and I want to avoid this.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM people where age in (30,25) or name = 'jeff' 
order by age desc
```

Comment: Question is, wouldn't that have to go through and get the age of everyone to be able to order them? If instead `age=30` it is a cpu intensive function, it'd have to compute it for every single one right?

Comment: Wrong, this query would list every "Jeff" older than 30 first.

Comment: It also doesn't appear to stage the query or include a rank in the results

Answer (score 0):

You have to introduce a calculated column to help you with sorting:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
,CASE 
   WHEN age = 30 THEN 1 
   WHEN age = 25 THEN 2 
   WHEN name='jeff' THEN 3 
   ELSE 4 
 END stage
FROM people 
ORDER BY stage ASC
```

Comment: That's cool, explains how to get the rank. But unfortunately if the WHERE clause is using CPU heavy functions it would have to compute them all - my database has 1 million rows, so trying to stage the execution. But perhaps it's not possible.

Comment: You have two options: either change the query to something like `WHERE BIRTHDAY BETWEEN...AND...` or precalculate the `age` column daily.

Comment: As you are rolling your own full-text search engine, are you sure you wouldn't be better off using an existing product? If yes, there's tons of [literature](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=text+search).